# C# .WithJson Invalid JSON Error

Tags: c#, json, pushsharp

I'm trying to build this JSon string as follows

```
push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(RegID)
                                  .WithJson(@"{""message"":"+Message+"}"));
```

Now whenever I run this, I get the InvalidCastException was unhandled/Invalid JSON detected! error message.

However when I do the following

```
push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(RegID)
                                  .WithJson(@"{""message"":""Hello World""}"));
```

It works perfectly fine.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions on how to get this working it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `Message` doesn't contain `"` or `\\` ?

Comment: @I4V Sorry I dont understand what you mean? 

string Message = "Hello World";  is what I'm using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're manually constructing your JSON (which you shouldn't do, really), you have to ensure `Message` contains the proper formatting for the portion of the JSON it contains.

```
string Message = "Hello World";
```

will result in JSON that doesn't include quotes around a string, which is invalid.  Ie:

```
{ "message" : Hello World }
```

You could add quotes manually, but what you *should* do is use a JSON library.  .NET has a simple one in [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).  With it you can do something like this and never worry about whether your `Message` contains the proper formatting.

```
var obj = new { message = "Hello World" };
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(obj);

push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(RegID)
                                            .WithJson(json));
```